# plotly subpot legend item spacing `legend_tracegroupgap`, how to define as percentage of figure height?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to make a function using plotly 5.9.0 that will reproduce a specific type of plot. I am having trouble aligning legend entries with their subplots, especially when the figure is resizable.

This is what i currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.subplots as sp
from plotly.offline import plot


def get_df(len_df):
    x = np.linspace(-1, 1, len_df)

    # Create a dictionary with the functions to use for each column
    funcs = {
        "column1": np.sin,
        "column2": np.cos,
        "column3": np.tan,
        "column4": np.arcsin,
        "column5": np.arccos,
        "column6": np.arctan
    }

    # Create an empty dataframe with the same index as x
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2022-01-01', periods=len(x), freq='H'))

    # Populate the dataframe with the functions
    for column, func in funcs.items():
        df[column] = func(x)
    return df


def plot_subplots(df, column_groups, fig_height=1000):
    # Create a figure with a grid of subplots
    fig = sp.make_subplots(rows=len(column_groups), shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True, vertical_spacing=.1)

    # Iterate over the list of column groups
    for i, group in enumerate(column_groups):
        # Iterate over the columns in the current group
        for column in group:
            # Add a scatter plot for the current column to the figure, specifying the row number
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[column], mode="lines", name=column, legendgroup=str(i)), row=i + 1, col=1)

    fig.update_layout(legend_tracegroupgap=fig_height/len(column_groups), height=fig_height)
    return fig

df = get_df(1000)
column_groups = [
    ['column1', 'column3'],
    ['column2', 'column4'],
    ['column5', 'column6']
]
fig = plot_subplots(df, column_groups)
plot(fig)
```

This produces a plot that looks like this:

[image]

How do I align my legend subgroups with the top of each corresponding plotly subplot?

If we can somehow relate the `legend_tracegroupgap` to the `height` of the figure that would be a great first step. This feels like such a logical thing to want that I feel like I'm missing something.

**In reply to r-beginners:**

I tried this:

```
tracegroupgap=(fig.layout.yaxis.domain[1] - fig.layout.yaxis.domain[0])*fig_height
```

Which works perfectly for a figure with a height of 1000. But not for a height of 500 pixels. I still have to subtract some value that has to do with the vertical spacing is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are few functions in plotly that allow strict size definitions other than figure size. The position of the legend in a subplot can also only be set by setting the spacing between legend groups as a pixel value (the default is 10px). So I used a function provided for development to check the area of the subplot.

```
dev_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development()

'yxais':{
...
domain': [0.7333333333333334, 1],
...
}
'yaxis2': {
...
'domain': [0.3666666666666667, 0.6333333333333333],
...
}
'yaxis3': {
...
'domain': [0, 0.26666666666666666],
...
}
```

```
fig.update_layout(legend_tracegroupgap=266, height=fig_height)
```

Since each subplot is drawn to the nearest 0.26 units, the gap was set at 266. However, this does not mean that we have derived a perfect value. I am sure other factors are still affecting this, and I hope to get answers from actual developers and others.

**Question has been updated so that if the height of the graph is 500px**

The default margins are 100px top and 80px bottom, so set them to 0.

```
def plot_subplots(df, column_groups, fig_height=500):
    # Create a figure with a grid of subplots
    fig = sp.make_subplots(rows=len(column_groups), shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True, vertical_spacing=.1)

    # Iterate over the list of column groups
    for i, group in enumerate(column_groups):
        # Iterate over the columns in the current group
        for column in group:
            # Add a scatter plot for the current column to the figure, specifying the row number
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[column], mode="lines", name=column, legendgroup=str(i)), row=i + 1, col=1)
    tracegroupgap = (fig.layout.yaxis.domain[1] - fig.layout.yaxis.domain[0])*fig_height
    print(fig.layout.yaxis.domain[0], fig.layout.yaxis.domain[1])
    print(tracegroupgap)
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=0,b=0,l=0,r=0))
    fig.update_layout(legend_tracegroupgap=tracegroupgap, height=fig_height)#fig_height/len(column_groups)
    return fig
```

Comment: I added a reply to your comment in an edit to my question.

Comment: This is my guess, but I think there is logic in there that ignores the margins if there is a certain height. The reason for this is that if the margins are set to 0, they would be placed in the optimal location.